# Powershell regex log entries that are X minutes old

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

I would like to run a script that scrapes a log every 5 minutes to determine how many entries have been written in that time. For example, if I want to count the number of entries between 16:30 and 16:34 I might do something like this:

```
$start=0
$end=4

$result = Select-String -Path "C:\Path\To\log\file.txt" -Pattern "16:3[\b($start|$end)\b]" -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
    Measure-Object |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

Write-Output $result
```

But this is pretty static and I would like something more dynamic that would allow me to run the script at any time and just count the entries for "the last five minutes". Is there a regex-ish way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$date = get-date

$h = $date.TimeOfDay.Hours
$end = $date.TimeOfDay.Minutes
$start = $end -5

$pattern = "$($h):[\b($start-$end)\b]"

....
```